# How to avoid creases on certain areas of a model when using subdivision modifier

Tags: modeling, shaders, edges, subdivision-surface, loop

**Sharp edges**

[image: Sharp edges edit mode]
[image: Sharp edges]

Bacically while trying to sharpen edges of one part of my model it causes another part of model, which needs to be smooth, to become sharper. I understand why this is happening but I wanted to know if there is anyway to prevent this

Comment: Are you using the Bevel modifier? Can you explain how you "sharpen" them?

Comment: Im using a subdivision modifier and using edge loops to sharpen the edges